# React Native: Saving array via AsyncStorage and retrieving it

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to get an array of objects from my `Redux-Store` state called `user` and save it to async storage and use `useState` with the `response` to `set the state` before I retrieve it and view it with the `FlatList` however I am getting an error along the lines of `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.` The `user` details is being set to the redux store in another component and then being retrieved from the current component I am displaying. Please could I get your help . I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!!!

```
const TheUser = (props) => {
    //user is an array from redux store
    const user = useSelector(state => state.account.cookbook)
    const [getUser, setGetUser] = useState()

    const saveUserAsync = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
    }
    saveUserAsync()

    AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(response => {
        setGetUser(response)
    })
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={getUser}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={itemData =>
                <MyUser
                    name={itemData.item.name}
                    image={itemData.item.imageUri}
                    details={itemData.item.details.val}
                />
            }
        />
    )
}
export default TheUser
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
let isMount = true
const TheUser = (props) => {
    //user is an array from redux store
    const user = useSelector(state => state.account.cookbook)

    // const [getUser, setGetUser] = useState()

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     const saveUserAsync = async () => {
    //         await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))

    //         const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    //         if (isMount)
    //             setGetUser(JSON.parse(response))
    //     }
    //     saveUserAsync()


    // }, [user])

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     isMount = true
    //     return () => {
    //         isMount = false
    //     }
    // }, [])
    return (
        <FlatList
            // data={getUser}
            data={user}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={itemData =>
                <MyUser
                    name={itemData.item.name}
                    image={itemData.item.imageUri}
                    details={itemData.item.details.val}
                />
            }
        />
    )
}
export default TheUser
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` hook to solve this problem.

`IS_MOUNTED` variable will track if component is mounted or not.

```
let IS_MOUNTED = false;   // global value

const TheUser = (props) => {
    //user is an array from redux store
    const user = useSelector(state => state.account.cookbook)
    const [getUser, setGetUser] = useState()

    const saveUserAsync = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
    }
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(response => {
        if(IS_MOUNTED)
         {
            setGetUser(JSON.parse(response));
         }
    });


    useEffect(() => { 
         IS_MOUNTED = true;
         saveUserAsync();
        return (() => {
            IS_MOUNTED = false;  
         })
     },[])
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={getUser}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={itemData =>
                <MyUser
                    name={itemData.item.name}
                    image={itemData.item.imageUri}
                    details={itemData.item.details.val}
                />
            }
        />
    )
}
export default TheUser
```

Comment: Thank you fir your detailed response. Is what I am doing right where I save the redux state before I view it in the flatList or is there a better way to do this. Please let me know.

Comment: Also I am only seeing the component update when I press save. How do I avoid this because when I add a new result on the emulator it adds it but i can't view it till i press save again on my file. How can I fix this?